# creating 'n' no. of list items on user input through "prompt()"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan't to replace a list item of an unordered list and generate 'n' list items in its place after clicking on it (n is input by the user on prompt when a list item is clicked).

I referred to the following link, but still couldn't make out a solution for my case:

[Generating list item x number of times, based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286407/generating-list-item-x-number-of-times-based-on-user-input)

This is what I tried but its not working:

HTML:

```
<ul id="list" onclick="inputNumber()">
<a href="#"><li>list-1</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>list-2</li></a>
<a href="#"><li>list-3</li></a>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
     list-style: none;
     display: inline;
   }
```

JavaScript:

```
function inputNumber() {

    var index = $(this).index();   
                     // to record the index of the clicked item 

    var inputNum = prompt("Divide By:");    
                     // input and store 'n' by the user

    var oldList = document.getElementById("list");  
                    // the main old list

    var garbage= oldList.removeChild(oldList.childNodes[index+1]); 
                   // remove the clicked item from the main list 

    var newList=document.createElement("li");  
                  // create new list item

    var i;

    for (i=1;i<=inputNum;i++)
    {
    list.append(newList.clone().text('list-'+i));
     // loop to clone and append 'n' list items in place of the previous one
    }

  }
```

JSfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/yoshi2095/k0jt8n7x/44/

Please help. Thanks.

edit:

- only the 'clicked' item should get replaced by the 'n' items input by the user at the same place of that 'clicked' item. Other list items should remain at their respective places as before.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/k0jt8n7x/46/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, but this is not removing the 'clicked' list item. And the list item is not getting 'replace' by 'n' items input by the user. They are getting 'added' along with all the previous ones. Thanks a lot for the help though :)

Comment: You should mention your requirments in your question too

Comment: I apologise for the same. I have made an edit. Thanks for correcting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xvf74fcf/)

There were a few issues you had in your code. One was you were forgetting `$()` around functions that were only for jQuery. You also were not removing the child elements correctly, the jQuery functions `$(this)` and `.remove()` and JavaScript `.children` together work to remove only the clicked element. You were also only creating one new element to add to the list, but you needed to create multiple, so I added that inside the for loop.

```
$("li").click(function() {
  var inputNum = prompt("Divide By:");
  var oldList = document.getElementById("list");
  for (var i=1;i<=inputNum; i++)
  {
  var newList=document.createElement("li");
  $(this).parent().append($(newList).text('list-'+i));
  }
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: I have made an edit to the question. I really apologise for not clearly mentioning the requirements. Please refer to the edit if you don't mind. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: I want just the 'clicked' child to be removed, not all.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update my fiddle, check it out again.

Comment: In your code (not jsfiddle but the one included here. your JSfiddle doesn't contain the same code), the 'clicked' list item is getting replaced by 'n' items correctly but its position is changing too. They a supposed to be at the same place as the 'clicked' one. But its almost done. Thanks a LOT for the help. I was stuck on this since days! Thanks! :)